# encrypted connection string in web.config

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config, connection-string

How can an encrypted connection string be read in the C# code when the encrypted connection string is kept in an external configuration file and specified by configSource attribute in the connectionStrings section of web.config of an asp.net application?

The external config file should only have connectionStrings node, but when it is encrypted, the configDataProvider node should also be present in the same file. And so it cannot be used in the configSource attribute.

I have encrypted connection strings and want to have it in external config file. How can this be handled?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Did you try putting the connection string section in the external file and _then_ encrypting it?

Comment: A little dated, but you can try this solution: [Encrypting string in an external config for ASP.NET](http://gregorybeamer.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/encrypting-string-in-an-external-config-for-asp-net/)

Comment: If it is put in the external file and then encrypted it the configProtectedData node will be inserted after which it won't be readable using the configSource attribute.

Answer (score 4):

In your app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="foo.config" />
    ...
</configuration>
```

and in your `foo.config`:

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>
                AQAAANCMnd8BFdE....
            </CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

and in your code:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someKey"]
```

Comment: I want to have the foo.config in plain text and encrypt during deployment and preferably not having to do anything manually like deleting any node.

Comment: @Sam, read about how encryption is done: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx. The process could be of course scripted and automated. What I have shown is how your configuration should look at runtime. In order to arrive at this configuration you could have unencrypted files containing the connection strings and script the encryption process described in the documentation. So go ahead and read this documentation to understand this process so that you could script it during build.

Comment: I have the connectionStrings as separate file foo.config. Say, I encrypt using a script during deployment using a -prov "Myprovider" switch which will insert the configProtectedData node in the foo.config. This will cause an error "The format of a configSource file must be an element containing the name of the section." when accessed within the C# code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. You cannot have connectionStrings directly in a separate file when encrypting. You must have a temporary .config file containing all the `<configuration>` sections with the unencrypted connection string. It is this temporary configuration file that you have to encrypt. Once you encrypt it you could extract the encrypted connection string into foo.config.

Comment: That's what I figured. But this extraction process, I need to have some scripts written for that.

Comment: Instead, I'm planning to have it as a separate config and read the strings from there without having any traces of it in web.config

Comment: Yes, of course that you need scripts for that. This what I am saying.